# Not able to enter password when logging in after boot

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, login

I'm running a raspberry pi 4b with raspberry pi os lite (which is debian without a GUI) and today while ssh'd in did a `sudo apt update`. There were a bunch of things that were available to upgrade ("`1114 packages can be upgraded`"). I didn't do the upgrade. I was trying to install some software. I did `sudo apt install poppler-utils`, which downloaded and then had a couple of errors.

```
Setting up libc6:armhf (2.33-7) .../usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorydpkg: error processing package libc6:armhf (--configure): installed libc6:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127Setting up libc6:arm64 (2.33-7) .../usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorydpkg: error processing package libc6:arm64 (--configure): installed libc6:arm64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127Errors were encountered while processing: libc6:armhf libc6:arm64E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I decided maybe I should `sudo apt upgrade` first. When I did that I got `sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?` and I then did `exit` (I was doing all this through ssh). Then I tried to ssh back in to the raspberry pi, several times, each with errors. First

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by fe80::d62b:8db5:a7c5:cc7%en0 port 22
```

Then `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` and then `ssh: connect to host server.local port 22: Connection refused`, which I continued to get every time I tried to log in after that.

So I went to the pi to physically log in. It was sitting at the login screen (it's normally headless, and I usually only login with ssh.) The login prompt cursor was there but the keyboard did nothing. So I rebooted by unplugging the pi and plugging it back in. When it booted up, it gave me a normal looking collection of boot messages, until toward the end it said `failed to start openbsd secure shell server` several times each followed by see `systemctl [something...something] for details`. Then it had the login prompt. I typed my username, hit enter, and **instead of asking for my password, it just said login incorrect and never let me put in a password**. I tried with root and with username pi but for all of them there was no opportunity to enter a password and I got login incorrect. Then after some time I also got login timed out after 60 seconds.

So now I can't ssh in, and I can't physically log in either. I tried ctrl-alt-f2 to get a new tty but it has the same problem where it doesn't give me a chance to put in a password. By the way, I've been using this install of raspberry pi os lite for over a year with no problems like this before day. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password) which seems like the same problem I'm having with logging in physically. I can't run anything though (like `sudo apt upgrade`) because I can't login. I can mount my disk on a different linux computer and see all the files, so I could look at logs but I'm not sure where to look.

Thanks for reading all this. I'd sure not like to have to wipe the drive and reinstall everything. I have the files so nothing is lost but it took a long time to get everything set up the way I wanted it. Any ideas for me?

Comment: I've been trying various things to get in: with the drive mounted on a different system, edited the /etc/passwd file to have no 'x', hoping this would let me login with a blank password. Didn't work. Then tried editing /etc/shadow and removed the password from my username there. Also didn't work. Tried adding a line to /etc/rc.local: "setsid /sbin/agetty -a root --noclear tty6 &", but this also didn't work (I got "authentication failure" on tty6 for a few seconds, then back to the non-working login screen.